# scrollTop is not working when the page zoomed out

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, zooming

I used the following code to autoscroll a textarea. First I read the current scroll position and then set it to new amount. When I Zoom out the page in (Google Chrome) the function won't work anymore. What is the logic between the **scrollTop** and zoom factor?

```js
function autoScroll(){
  var currentScroll=parseInt($("#text").scrollTop());
  var step=1;
  var amount=currentScroll + step;
  var t=setTimeout(function(){$("#text").scrollTop(amount);autoScroll()},50);
}
    
autoScroll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text" style="height:100px">Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book. It usually begins with:

“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.”
The purpose of lorem ipsum is to create a natural looking block of text (sentence, paragraph, page, etc.) that doesn't distract from the layout. A practice not without controversy, laying out pages with meaningless filler text can be very useful when the focus is meant to be on design, not content.

The passage experienced a surge in popularity during the 1960s when Letraset used it on their dry-transfer sheets, and again during the 90s as desktop publishers bundled the text with their software. Today it's seen all around the web; on templates, websites, and stock designs. Use our generator to get your own, or read on for the authoritative history of lorem ipsum.</textarea>
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem and noticed that as soon as chrome's window is zoomed in or out, `scrollTop` returns the same value every time `autoScroll` function is called. Not sure why this happens but `scrollTop` returning the same value causes the `autoScroll` function to stop working. Created a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/sXWLrdseXSaZQpR9?open=lib%2Fscript.js) that shows how you can fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you. In brief does it scroll one more pixel  when the main calculation fails? @Yousaf

Comment: No, it only scrolls as long as the condition is true: as long as the current scroll position is less than the scroll height of the text area.